# wasync client on Android unable to receive push notifications from Primefaces - Atmosphere server

Tags: android, primefaces, push, atmosphere

Software Stack:

- Tomcat v7.0.62
- Primefaces 5.0 application with Atmosphere (@PushEndpoint) - atmosphere-runtime v.2.1.3
- External Android app with Atmosphere Wasync client v1.4.3

We have 2 separate applications. On the one hand, we have a PrimeFaces application that, among other things, send notifications. On the other hand, we have an independent android app. We're trying to figure out the best way  for PF browser clients to send/receive messages with standalone android client using wAsync.

It seems that the android app is able to connect successfully. But, send notification with PF didn't have any effect, the app doesn't receive it, and there were no error messages on either android app or the server.

This is the primefaces code:

```
@PushEndpoint("/servicios")
public class ServiciosPushControlador implements ServiciosControladorListener {
    @Override
    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public String servicioActualizado(Servicio servicio) {
        return "update";
    }
}
```

And web.xml configuration for Atmosphere

```
<!-- PUSH PrimeFaces-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And this is the Android code:

```
public <ResultType> void notificationSuscriber(Function<ResultType> succesFunction, Function<IOException> errorFunction, final Class<ResultType> clazz) throws IOException {
        RequestBuilder request = client.newRequestBuilder()
                .method(org.atmosphere.wasync.Request.METHOD.GET)
                .uri("http://192.168.0.101:8080/calview/primepush/servicios")
                .encoder(new Encoder<ResultType, String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String encode(ResultType s) {
                        try {
                            return mapper.writeValueAsString(s);
                        } catch (IOException iOEx) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(iOEx);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .decoder(new Decoder<String, ResultType>() {

                    @Override
                    public ResultType decode(Event e, String s) {
                        if (s.length() == 0)
                            return null;
                        if (e.equals(Event.MESSAGE)) {
                            try {
                                return new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, clazz);
                            } catch (IOException iOEx) {
                                iOEx.printStackTrace();
                                return null;
                            }
                        } else
                            return null;
                    }
                })
                .transport(org.atmosphere.wasync.Request.TRANSPORT.WEBSOCKET);

        Socket socket = client.create();
        socket.on("message", succesFunction)
                .on(errorFunction)
                .open(request.build());
    }
```

Comment: what **does** happen?

Comment: The android app doesn't receive the notifications.

Comment: That is what does NOT happen (you yourself write it... **doesn't**) That is the end-user experience. Think like a developer. Can you see the appserver receiving the connection from the android client? Does it pass through the push servlet? etc

Comment: Now, the Android app receives "OPEN" when I send the connection request to Primefaces, and "CLOSE" when stops primefaces application. But it still doesn't receive notifications.

Comment: what do you mean by 'now'? Sounds like it did not do this before, but that it does now. Or am I wrong? And if I'm right, is that still with the code above? Any changes? Did you try this from an simple 'main' in a pojo?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been clear, I had a wrong IP address on Android app.

Comment: Tried it outside android in a normal class with a main? If that fails to it is easier to reproduce for me

Comment: I'm confused. I tried this in a simple Java class. It seems that the client connects correctly. However, it receives a "MESSAGE" notification that looks like it has not been sent by primepush. The message contains " ". I'll try to implement primepush on a simple app to avoid interferences from another push channels.